# Show hide content text hover in css/html

Tags: html, css, hover

I have problem in html/css

I got some texts like

```
hey-1title
hey test
hey-2title
hey2test
hey-3title
hey3test
hey-4title
hey4test
hey-5title
hey5test
```

I want to show hey test only and hide hey2test hey3test hey4test hey5test. and, they're specified with a title of hey2 hey3 hey4 hey5

Like,

```
hey-1title
hey test
```

will show only.

rest won,t but only titles

and when i move my mouse to one of the other title
hey test disappears and hey2test will show ( if i moved my mouse to hey-2title.

and same with the rest.

Comment: Ya that's great, so did you tried out yourself first?

Comment: Ahmed, when you move the mouse over the revealed div, do you want it to stay visible? And how it should look like? One example: http://demos.w3avenue.com/cross-browser-pure-css3-vertical-accordion/

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Head</title>
<style>
.text{
display:none;
}
.title:hover+.text{display:block}

</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="title">hey-1title</div>
        <div class="text">hey test</div>
        <div class="title">hey-2title</div>
        <div class="text">hey2 test</div>
        <div class="title">hey-3title</div>
        <div class="text">hey3 test</div>
        <div class="title">hey-4title</div>
        <div class="text">hey4 test</div>
        <div class="title">hey-5title</div>
        <div class="text">hey5 test</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you do this, all the text classes will show... :P EDIT: No, I'm wrong, this works perfect :)

Comment: have you tried it.. :D, try it before comment ... there is "+" selector combinator which selects immidiate sibling, so only corresponding title's text div will display...

Comment: Yes yes, you have reason... sorry :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use some like

```
.hey1:hover{
 display:none;
}
```

or an jquery slider up and down function

Comment: Still, did not work. while I'm using <div class="hey1"> in the html for the text i want to use and still, not hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/lUgm2z37IQKWCqlJGIyi?p=preview)

Here you can see child menu when you hover on parent menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: (You have to put test1 and later test1Hover (you can't separate it)):

**HTML**

```
<div id="test1">Test 1</div>
<div id="test1Hover">Test 1 Hover</div>
<div id="test2">Test 2</div>
<div id="test2Hover">Test 2 Hover</div>
<div id="test3">Test 3</div>
<div id="test3Hover">Test 3 Hover</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    #test1Hover{
        display:none;
    }
    #test2Hover{
        display:none;
    }
    #test3Hover{
        display:none;
    }

#test1:hover + #test1Hover{
    display: block;
}

#test2:hover + #test2Hover{
    display: block;
}

#test3:hover + #test3Hover{
    display: block;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hGp7P/1/